# Ionic 2 Observable.timer destroyed on back button

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an `Observable.timer` countdown and when a user leaves the page I want that timer to still be active if they decide to come back later. For example, I only want the timer to be removed when a **specific date** **and time** are reached.

I have tried to implement this but when I click back button the timer get destroyed and the endTimer() callback gets called.

**TIMER FUNCTION**

```
   countDown: any;
   counter = 1*900;
   tick = 1000;

 newtimer() {
   // create session 
   this.storage.set('dateCreated', 'timer_started');
   // create timer
   this.countDown = Observable.timer(0, this.tick)
      .take(this.counter)
      .map(() => --this.counter).finally(() => this.endTimer()); 
 }
```

Comment: Is this for a specific page? Or is it more like a session for the whole app? And where do you call your function `newtimer()`?

Comment: Sounds like you have this function in a component/page, when it would better serve you in a service.

Comment: It is for a specific page. It is called in the constructor of the page with the timer function

Answer (score 0):

When you leave a page in ionic it will be destroyed. So that timer, which is member var of that page, is destroyed.

If you want that timer keep running, you should put it in some service. Because the service is singleton can will not be destroyed when a page is removed.

Comment: I have added it to a service but still the timer ends when I exit the page and if I try to reenter it starts again from scratch

Comment: how you import and inject the service?